# EclipseFP issues with Hoogle

Tags: eclipse, haskell, eclipse-fp

Installed [EclipseFP](http://eclipsefp.github.io/), looks without any observable issues. However, when I start Eclipse, I get this:

[image: The Hoogle database is empty. Do you want to download the required information?]

Whether I click yes or no, the same thing happens on next restart.

Also, in the Hoogle view, I see this:

[image: TNo database loaded or Hoogle not present]

even though I see the databases seemingly OK in `workspace\.metadata\.plugins\net.sf.eclipsefp.haskell.browser\scion-browser-0.2-dbs`:

```
hackage.db  123.71 MB   31.10.2014 09:42:18 Data Base File  A
local.db    3.06 MB 31.10.2014 10:20:53 Data Base File  A
```

In the scion-browser console, I have this on startup:

```
>> {"rebuild":true,"filepath":"C:\\eclipse\\workspace\\.metadata\\.plugins\\net.sf.eclipsefp.haskell.browser\\scion-browser-0.2-dbs\\local.db","command":"load-local-db"}
Local database loaded
"ok"
>> {"module":"","command":"get-modules","db":"_all"}
>> {"rebuild":false,"filepath":"C:\\eclipse\\workspace\\.metadata\\.plugins\\net.sf.eclipsefp.haskell.browser\\scion-browser-0.2-dbs\\hackage.db","command":"load-hackage-db"}
Hackage databas"ok"
e loaded
>> {"module":"Prelude","command":"get-declarations","db":"_all"}
>> {"path":"C:\\eclipse\\workspace\\.metadata\\.plugins\\net.sf.eclipsefp.haskell.ui\\sandbox\\.cabal-sandbox\\bin\\hoogle.exe","command":"extra-hoogle-path"}
"ok"
>> {"command":"hoogle-check"}
C:\eclipse\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\net.sf.eclipsefp.haskell.ui\sandbox\.cabal-sandbox\bin\hoogle.exe

"Error"
```

Looks like hoogle is not working from the command line either:

```
C:\>cd C:\eclipse\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\net.sf.eclipsefp.haskell.ui\sandbox\.cabal-sandbox\bin\

C:\eclipse\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\net.sf.eclipsefp.haskell.ui\sandbox\.cabal-sandbox\bin>hoogle fmap
Could not find some databases: default
Searching in:
  .
  C:\eclipse\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\net.sf.eclipsefp.haskell.ui\sandbox\.cabal-sandbox\x86_64-windows-ghc-7.8.3\hoogle-4.2.36\databases

There are no available databases, generate them with: hoogle data

C:\eclipse\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\net.sf.eclipsefp.haskell.ui\sandbox\.cabal-sandbox\bin>
```

Any ideas here? I'll add additional information as needed, just not sure what would be useful, let me know and I'll edit.

Comment: In the console, there is a console called "Scion-browser". Look into it to see what it says and if there is any issue shown.

Comment: @JPMoresmau Thanks for the tip - see my edit and my answer / solution - let me know what you think / if you have additional comments. Not sure what I should have done regarding to this when installing EclipseFP, so it works properly from the get go - any hints? This might prove useful as a FAQ entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like for some reason hoogle did not work from the command line either. May be related to this:

```
C:\eclipse\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\net.sf.eclipsefp.haskell.ui\sandbox\.cabal-sandbox\bin>hoogle data
Downloading downloads/platform.cabal
WARNING: Could not find command line program wget.
  You may be able to install it from:
  http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm
WARNING: Could not find command line program curl.
  You may be able to install it from:
  http://curl.haxx.se/download.html
hoogle: Error when running Shake build system:
* default.hoo
* platform.hoo
* platform.txt
* downloads/platform.cabal.cache
* downloads/platform.cabal
Could not find downloader, neither curl nor wget are on the $PATH.
```

I have [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) installed, so I fixed this by running `hoogle data` from withing Cygwin terminal, which had `wget` available in the path and that seems to have solved the issue.

Comment: Yes, see http://jpmoresmau.blogspot.fr/2011/08/hoogle-command-line-on-windows.html. I should probably add that in the FAQ, yes.

Comment: @JPMoresmau Agreed, adding that to the FAQ would be useful!